# How do I solve the Agbaar's Academy Slowing Pt 1 Puzzle?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

I keep running about 3 hit points shy of being able to defeat the boss. Eventually I'll probably end up solving this through trial and error, but what are the steps I need to take to defeat this puzzle?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And, naturally, *the very next thing I tried turned out to be the answer*. I'd been forgetting that you automatically get first strike on any enemy that you are higher level than, and nothing in this particular puzzle makes mention of that fact.

The trick is to kill the first enemy before picking up the sword, so that you first strike him and don't take any retaliatory damage. After that, you hack your way to the boss, smack him once with the sword still equipped, and then convert it so that you are no longer slowed and WEYTWUT him so that you end up getting first strike to finish him off.

1. Kill the first Meat Man.
2. Pick up the Really Big Sword.
3. Kill the next Meat Man.
4. Pick up the WEYTWUT glyph.
5. Kill the third Meat Man.
6. Attack Eeblis once.
7. Convert your sword (note that if you do that before attack him once, you won't do enough damage on the next attack to finish him off).
8. Cast WEYTWUT on Eeblis.
9. Attack him one more time to finish him off.